# How to delete isolated pixels in ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, editing

I want to know that it is possible or not to edit the raster pixel in ArcGIS.
I want to delete isolated pixel and I want to delete some pixel by manually.
please tell me how can i do it manually or application of tools.

Comment: Very closely related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41064/raster-noise-reduction-and-edge-smoothing.  This explains how to delete isolated pixels (or small groups of pixels).

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the situation you have a few options:

1) The [Region Group tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000039000000.htm) will allow you to isolate individual pixels, which can then be filtered based on count.

2) The [Con tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000005000000.htm) can be used to remove (set null) or change the value of pixels if you can identify them by their values.

3) A variety of filters can be used to remove isolated pixels (e.g. majority filter). You can combine this with a mask if you don't want to filter the entire raster.

4) If you're looking to just display the raster you can just clean it up in something like Photoshop.

In terms of manually performing these types of edits, [this related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25120/manually-edit-a-raster-to-improve-a-classification) (including solution) is probably your best best given that you can't just edit individual pixels with something like a simple toolbar.

Comment: Re. 1) No need to convert to polygon. If the output regiongroup raster is in ESRI Grid format, the Con and Lookup (in ArcGIS 10+) functions can be used to mask, i.e. `SetNull(Lookup(RegionGroup("SomeRaster"),"count") == 1, "SomeRaster")`

Comment: You're right - I edited the answer to reflect your correction. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the ArcScan extension? I've used a tool on the toolbar to remove individual pixels. Can't  remember the name of the tool but have a look at the help file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Spatial analyst tool -> Conditional -> set Null to erase select cell,
You can see here  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKs-QWMGlvI