# Edit raster classification manually using polygons in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, raster-calculator

I want to edit the elevation/z values of certain zones on a raster in ArcMap. I followed this example by creating a polygon, assigning a value of 7.5, then converting the polygon to a raster, finally using the raster calculator to create a new layer: 
[Manually edit a raster to improve a classification?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25120/manually-edit-a-raster-to-improve-a-classification)

However, after using the raster calculator I was left with a raster containing the values of the polygons only, with the remaining values from my original raster as 'nodata'.

Comment: Exactly what formula did you use in the raster calculator? Does your polygon raster match extent/resolution to your original raster? Are they using the same coordinate system? Also note we have several questions on replacing values in one raster with values from another - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=arcgis+replace+raster+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by creating a second polygon around the entire raster extent, to which I assigned a value of zero. Previously, the shapefile only contained a single polygon, hence the cells outside of it had no value. Thus, the new shapefile and raster contain a value of 7.5 at the polygon and 0 elsewhere.