# Is it possible to reclassify rasters manually?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3

Is it possible to change raster cell values individually or as a group?

Currently, I am digitizing around cells I want to change and then doing a polygon to raster conversion and then a merge to new raster.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25120/manually-edit-a-raster-to-improve-a-classification

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  I note that you have not yet taken the [Tour].  Please do that because it leads into a much better understanding of how this site works.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.3;   Is it possible using ArcGIS or any other software.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide requested clarifications like these.  Potential answerers may or may not read the comments on a question.