# Changing land use land cover classes in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, land-cover, land-use

I have a tiff file containing raster data of land use land cover (LULC) classes.

Each pixel has a pixel value in the form of RGB values of the corresponding LULC class, need to change the pixel values of certain regions on the map and make a new map with revised LULC classification.

How can I do that in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Are you trying to reclassify single pixels, or entire categories (like combining "wheat" and "soy" into "crop")?

Answer (score 1):

The [Reclassify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) or [Conditional](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) tools will help you is you are trying to reclassify an entire category of pixels.

If you want to reclassify individual pixels there isn't a clean way to do it in ArcGIS, but you could [look at this thread for some work arounds](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25120/manually-editing-raster-to-improve-classification-using-arcgis-desktop).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I did it in a different way without using ArcGIS.